# How do I randomise my pictures in my game?

Tags: javascript

I have a game where you have to guess which of the 3 pots has the gold behind it. I want it so that every time a user clicks a pot, it randomises the pots and allows the user to choose again but the gold has moved to possibly another place but possibly the same as it will be randomised.

This the HTML that I have at the moment:

```
<div id="content"> 
<center>
<p>Lives: <span id="lives"></span></p>
<p>Score: <span id="score"></span></p>
<p id="game_status"></p>
<p>
<img id="pot1" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" onclick="clickMeIDFunction('pot1')">

<img id="pot2" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" onclick="clickMeIDFunction2('pot2')">

<img id="pot3" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" onclick="clickMeIDFunction3('pot3')">
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
var pots = new Array("nope.gif","nope.gif","gold-bar-icon.png");

function shuffle(pots){
    for(swaps=0; swaps<3; swaps++){
        shuffle1=Math.floor(Math.random()*pots.length);
        shuffle2=Math.floor(Math.random()*pots.length);
        temp=pots[shuffle1];
        pots[shuffle1]=pots[shuffle2];
        pots[shuffle2]=temp;
    }
}

lives=3;
score=0;

function refreshGame(){
    for(var i = 1 ; i<=3 ; i++){
      document.getElementById('pot'+i).src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif";
    }
}

function clickMeIDFunction(theElementID){
    var theElement = document.getElementById(theElementID);
    theElement.src = "nope.gif";
    lives--;
    setTimeout(refreshGame,1000);
    update_game_info()
}

function clickMeIDFunction2(theElementID){
    var theElement = document.getElementById(theElementID);
    theElement.src = 'nope.gif';
    lives--;
    setTimeout(refreshGame,1000);
    update_game_info()
}

function clickMeIDFunction3(theElementID){
    var theElement = document.getElementById(theElementID);
    theElement.src = "gold-bar-icon.png";
    score++;
    setTimeout(refreshGame,1000);
    update_game_info();
}


function update_game_info(){
    document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = lives;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    if (lives == 0){
        document.getElementById("game_status").innerHTML = "Game Over!";
    }
}

update_game_info();
```

Comment: You already have a shuffle function. Work from that.

Comment: But not sure how to get it to work:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess you could make it a bit easier to modify afterwards, and to keep it more together, as a complete game.

I believe you could make it yourself lots easier by only randomizing a nr, and then checking if the random nr corresponds with the image being clicked.

By separating the functions that need do the different aspects of your game, a reset and start method can easily be implemented.

The nr of pots that are available are dynamically created, as well as the lives and the points given per correct guess and miss, which images you wish to use, and where the elements should be placed. The game is currently run when the window gets loaded :)

```js
var game = (function() {
  function Game(options) {
    this.options = options;
    this.imageSet = options.imageSet;
    this.waiting = false;

    // sets the current pot of Gold (0 >= nr < this.options.totalPots)
    this.setPotOfGold = function() {
      this.currentPot = parseInt(Math.random() * this.options.totalPots);
    };

    this.createPots = function() {
      var el = document.getElementById(this.options.gameTargets.playfield),
        i,
        len,
        img;
      if (el) {
        for (i = 0, len = this.options.totalPots; i < len; i++) {
          // show the cards, with the guess card on top
          img = document.createElement('img');
          img.addEventListener('click', this.guessImage.bind(this, i));
          img.src = this.imageSet.turn;
          img.id = 'picture-' + i;
          el.appendChild(img);
        }
      }
    };

    this.correctGuess = function() {
      var that = this;
      this.score += this.options.pointsPerHit;
      
      this.showMessage('Correct guess, next round is coming!');
      setTimeout(function() {
        that.reset();
      }, 2500);

      return this.imageSet.correct;
    };

    this.wrongGuess = function() {
      var that = this;
      this.score += this.options.pointsPerMiss;
      this.lives--;

      console.log(this.lives);
      if (this.lives < 0) {
        this.showMessage('Game over! The game will automatically restart!');
        setTimeout(function() {
          that.lives = that.options.maxLives;
          that.score = 0;
          that.reset();
        }, 2500);
      }
      return this.imageSet.incorrect;
    };
    
    this.showMessage = function(message) {
      var el = document.getElementById('message-container');
      if (!el) {
        el = document.createElement('div');
        el.id = 'message-container';
        document.body.appendChild(el);
      }
      el.className = 'message';
      el.innerHTML  = message;
      this.waiting = true;
    };
    
    this.hideMessage = function(message) {
      var el = document.getElementById('message-container');
      if (el) {
        el.className = 'hidden';
      }
      this.waiting = false;
    };

    this.guessImage = function(index) {
      var real_image, el = document.getElementById('picture-' + index);
      if (this.waiting || el.src !== this.imageSet.turn) {
        // already clicked that one
        return;
      }
      if (this.currentPot === index) {
        real_image = this.correctGuess();
      } else {
        real_image = this.wrongGuess();
      }
      el.src = real_image;
      this.setScoreboard();
    };

    this.init = function() {
      // reset score stuff
      this.lives = this.options.maxLives;
      this.score = 0;
      // initialize
      this.createPots();
      // reset (that sets the initial pot of gold and returns the src's)
      this.reset();
    };

    this.setScoreboard = function () {
      var lblLives = document.getElementById(this.options.gameTargets.lives),
        lblScore = document.getElementById(this.options.gameTargets.score);

      console.log('setScoreBoard');
      lblLives.innerHTML = this.lives;
      lblScore.innerHTML = this.score;
    };

    this.reset = function() {
      this.hideMessage();
      this.setPotOfGold();
      var el = document.getElementById(this.options.gameTargets.playfield),
        i, len, img;
      if (el) {
        for (i = 0, len = this.options.totalPots; i < len; i++) {
          img = document.getElementById('picture-' + i);
          img.src = this.imageSet.turn;
        }
      }
      this.setScoreboard();
    };
  }

  function resetGame() {
    if (typeof game.current === 'undefined') {
      // first run of the game, no game defined yet...
      game.current = new Game({
        gameTargets: {
          playfield: 'game-container',
          lives: 'lblLives',
          score: 'lblScore'
        },
        maxLives: 5,
        pointsPerMiss: -5,
        pointsPerHit: 10,
        totalPots: 5,
        imageSet: {
          correct: 'http://www.moonbattery.com/archives/pot_of_gold.jpg',
          incorrect: 'http://www.boosshing.co.uk/images/news/2026679582-Boossh-Noodles.jpg',
          turn: 'http://blog.payonomy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Question-Mark.png'
        }
      });
      game.current.init();
    } else {
      game.current.reset();
    }
  }

  window.game = {
    reset: resetGame
  };
  return game;
}());

window.addEventListener('load', game.reset);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.scoreboard {
  border: solid #a0a0a0 1px;
  box-shadow: red 2px 2px;
  background-color: #666666;
}
.scoreboard .label {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.scoreboard .value {
  background-color: #efefef;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: right;
}
.scoreboard td {
  padding: 5px;
}
.container {
  border: solid #a0a0a0 1px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.message
{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 240px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -120px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.container img
{
  width: 120px; height: 120px;
}
.container img:hover
{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="game-scoreboard" class="scoreboard">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Lives:</td>
      <td class="value"><span id="lblLives">0</span>
      </td>
      <td class="label">Score:</td>
      <td class="value"><span id="lblScore">0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="game-container" class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working for me. It's not a perfect shuffle algorithm, but it does rearrange the items in the `pots` array. If you want an ideal shuffle algorithm, take a look at [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). You don't seem to be calling your function anywhere, however. Add a `shuffle(pots)` call to wherever you want the randomization to happen, either `refresh_game_info` or `update_game_info` or both.

That takes care of the array, but that's not yet connected to the images in the DOM or how they decide which pot has been selected and whether there's gold behind it or not. You could make your shuffle algorithm rearrange the pots elements, which could look fancy if you want to [animate it](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/). The simpler thing to do is to unite the onclick methods and use the ID of the clicked element.

```
<img id="pot1" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" 
    onclick="potClicked(this)">

<img id="pot2" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" 
    onclick="potClicked(this)">

<img id="pot3" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot"
    onclick="potClicked(this)">
```

In this code, referencing `this` to the `onclick` handler passes the DOM element itself into the `potClicked` function. Then you can get rid of the three `onclick` functions you have in your code and do the logic in a single method.

```
function potClicked(theElement){
    // This is error prone! Only works with elements that have an ID conforming
    // to "pot#": starts with 3 letters followed by 1 digit number.
    // Use smarter function if you have different or longer IDs.
    var id = parseInt(theElement.id.substr(3,1));
    var image = pots[id];
    if(image == "nope.gif") {
        // Guessed wrong
        lives--;
    } else {
        // Guessed right
        score++;
    }
    theElement.src = image;
    lives--;
    setTimeout(refreshGame,1000);
    update_game_info()
}
```

And that should just about wrap it up.